# ASP.NET GridView format changes when in edit mode

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, styling

This my GridView when the page first loads:
[image]

Now this is what it looks like when the user clicks the edit button:
[image]

The GridView's format clearly looks much better in edit mode, so I am trying to edit its styling to make it always looks like that. I have tried to edit the width and height in rowstyle, but the settings are only applied if they will make the the cells larger, and I obviously want them to be smaller. I have not been able to find or write a method to resize the cells programmatically either.

Here is the code for the GridView and its SqlDataSource (I omitted the update parameters for this post):

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:1500px">
            <asp:GridView id="maintenanceGridView" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="maintenanceDataSource"
                AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50" 
                OnRowEditing="maintenanceGridView_RowEditing"
                OnRowUpdating="maintenanceGridView_RowUpdating"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="maintenanceGridView_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowDataBound="maintenanceGridView_RowDataBound"
                AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
                <rowstyle backcolor="LightCyan"/>
                <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="PaleTurquoise"/>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <h3>No Records Found!!</h3>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource id="maintenanceDataSource"
            DataSourceMode="DataSet"
            SelectCommand="AMT_GetMaintenanceView"
            UpdateCommand="AMT_UpdateMaintenance"
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iandcInternDBConn %>"
            runat="server">
            <UpdateParameters>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

I have no idea what is causing the GridView's format to change. I tried looking for its default CSS but found nothing, and Internet Explorer's developer tools are telling me that the CSS is the same in edit mode as it is in view mode.

Any help or further insight is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set cells width programmatically in `RowDataBound` event as:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
    e.Row.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
}
```

Comment: I put that code in a for loop so it would apply on all cells. It only had an effect if I was making the cells larger than their current values. Thank you for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a small temporary workaround by always forcing the GridView into edit mode on the first row; even if the users try to cancel the edit.

I do so by adding code to the Page_Load and RowDataBound events

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Force the gridview into edit mode always becuase its formatting looks a million times better
        GridView1.EditIndex = 0;
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        // Default to edit mode
        if (GridView1.EditIndex == -1)
            GridView1.EditIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this in your CSS:

```
.GridViewEditRow input[type=text] { /*for text boxes use td for every cell*/
        width: 50px;
    }
```